# How to make Processing autosave on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, processing

I often forget to save Processing sketch changes and commit the incomplete version. I forgive myself making this mistake because almost any other Mac OS X applications are auto-saving their changes on the fly. Is there a way to make Processing doing the same?

Answer (score 0):

No. Just get into the habit of hitting save more often.

Edit: The whole editor is open-source so you could add the feature yourself, but I would expect that "feature" to be more trouble than it's worth.